# weird form redirection in zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

My form has a weird redirection problem.

When I give form action="/pdp/policy-info" it goes /pdp/pdp/policy-info.

But when I give form action ="policy-info" it goes to "/policy-info".
I want it to go to "/pdp/policy-info" and I am not sure why this is happening

The url of the form is pdp/client-info.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function myrequest(e) {
        var lead_id = $('#lead_id').val();
        $.ajax({
             method: "GET",
            url: "/pdp/fetch-client-data/",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data: {
                lead_id: lead_id
            },
            success: function( responseObject ) {
                if(responseObject !=null){
                $('#client_name').val( responseObject.client_name );
                $('#state').val(responseObject.state);
                }
                else{
                    alert('Could not find lead id!');
                }

            },
            failure: function() 
            {
                alert('fail');
            }
        });
    }

    $('#fetchFields').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        myrequest();
    });
    $("#lead_id").bind("change", function(e)
    {
      myrequest(); 
    });
});

</script>

<div id="client-box">
<form action ="pdp/policy-info/" method='post'>

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the url of the form? Provide the source.

Comment: How does the source look like? Is there some javascript?

Comment: I have some jquery as displayed above.But i dont think that is causing the problem

Comment: Zend Framework has a url view helper. Use it to make your application more portable and you won't run into these sorts of problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="client-box">
<form action ="/pdp/policy-info" method='post'>

</form>
</div>
```

It is important to use the absolute path (`/pdp/policy-info`). Not the relative one (`pdp/policy-info`).

Comment: From a view, you may want to consider using the [baseUrl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl) helper as well.  `<form action="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('pdp/policy-info'); ?>">` as that results in `/pdp/policy-info` or `/some/path/pdp/policy-info` if your application lives in `/some/path`.  It also makes the code more portable.